# Add text to ASP.NET MenuItem web control Text attribute with an existing Resource file reference in it

Tags: asp.net, web-controls

I have this line of code in a web page

```
<asp:MenuItem Text="<%$ Resources:AppGlobal , Uitloggen %>"/>
```

Which outputs "Log in" in the menu item when rendered

I want to add a prefix, "foo: Log in", for example

Is this possible? My failed guesses are variations of

```
<asp:MenuItem Text="'foo:' + <%$ Resources:AppGlobal , Uitloggen %>"/>
```

Caveat: the addition must be made in the markup not the codebase

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Additional note: I'm not a .NET developer. I'm a front-end developer tasked with making some front-end changes, hence stipulation that I can't change the codebase - they won't let me regardless of my skill set. FUN TIMES!!